# Zero fill data frame forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill a dataframe with zeros, however **I do not want to touch leading NaNs**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', periods=9, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': pd.Series([np.nan]*3 + [20, 30, 40] + [np.nan]*3, rng)})

2016-06-01     NaN
2016-06-02     NaN
2016-06-03     NaN
2016-06-04    20.0
2016-06-05    30.0
2016-06-06    40.0
2016-06-07     NaN
2016-06-08     NaN
2016-06-09     NaN
```

The df I want after filling/replacing is this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'data': pd.Series([np.nan]*3 + [20, 30, 40] + [0.]*3, rng)})

2016-06-01     NaN
2016-06-02     NaN
2016-06-03     NaN
2016-06-04    20.0
2016-06-05    30.0
2016-06-06    40.0
2016-06-07     0.0
2016-06-08     0.0
2016-06-09     0.0
```

Since `fillna()` only allows value or method and `fillna(0)` replaces **all NaNs, including leading**, I was hoping replace could jump in here, but

```
df.replace([np.nan], 0, method='ffill')
```

also replaces all NaNs.

**How can I zero fill values only after the first non-NaN value, also with multiple data columns?**

Comment: Could you define "leading `Nan`s" a little more precisely - I assume it is all the `NaN`s in a column until the first non-`NaN` datapoint is reached?  So, for example, if we adapted your example so that the first row contained `10`, you'd want to replace all `NaN`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can find first `group` of `NaN` by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) all other values:

```
print (df.data.notnull().cumsum())
2016-06-01    0
2016-06-02    0
2016-06-03    0
2016-06-04    1
2016-06-05    2
2016-06-06    3
2016-06-07    3
2016-06-08    3
2016-06-09    3
Freq: D, Name: data, dtype: int32

print (df.data.mask(df.data.notnull().cumsum() != 0, df.data.fillna(0)))
2016-06-01     NaN
2016-06-02     NaN
2016-06-03     NaN
2016-06-04    20.0
2016-06-05    30.0
2016-06-06    40.0
2016-06-07     0.0
2016-06-08     0.0
2016-06-09     0.0
Freq: D, Name: data, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

With multiple columns it works nice too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': pd.Series([np.nan]*3 + [20, 30, 40] + [np.nan]*3, rng), 
                   'data1': pd.Series([np.nan]*2 + [20, 30, 40,30] + [np.nan]*3, rng),
                   'data2': pd.Series([np.nan]*1 + [10,20, 20, 30, 40] + [np.nan]*3, rng)})

print (df.mask(df.notnull().cumsum() != 0, df.fillna(0)))
            data  data1  data2
2016-06-01   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-02   NaN    NaN   10.0
2016-06-03   NaN   20.0   20.0
2016-06-04  20.0   30.0   20.0
2016-06-05  30.0   40.0   30.0
2016-06-06  40.0   30.0   40.0
2016-06-07   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-08   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-09   0.0    0.0    0.0
```

EDIT2 by [`DSM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810688/zero-fill-data-frame-forward-fill/37811092#comment63086594_37811092) comment - nicer is use [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
print (df.mask(df.notnull().cummax(), df.fillna(0)))
            data  data1  data2
2016-06-01   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-02   NaN    NaN   10.0
2016-06-03   NaN   20.0   20.0
2016-06-04  20.0   30.0   20.0
2016-06-05  30.0   40.0   30.0
2016-06-06  40.0   30.0   40.0
2016-06-07   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-08   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-09   0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Instead of using `df.notnull().cumsum() != 0`, you could just use `df.notnull().cummax()`, I think.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I add it to answer.

Comment: That's a very nice one!

Answer (score 4):

you can do it using [last_valid_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) function:

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]:
            data  data1  data2
2016-06-01   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-02   NaN    NaN   10.0
2016-06-03   NaN   20.0   20.0
2016-06-04  20.0   30.0   20.0
2016-06-05   NaN   40.0    NaN
2016-06-06  40.0   30.0   40.0
2016-06-07   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-08   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-09   NaN    NaN    NaN

In [81]: %paste
first_valid_idx = df.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index()).to_frame()
df = df.fillna(0)
for ix, r in first_valid_idx.iterrows():
    df.loc[df.index < r[0], ix] = np.nan
## -- End pasted text --

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
            data  data1  data2
2016-06-01   NaN    NaN    NaN
2016-06-02   NaN    NaN   10.0
2016-06-03   NaN   20.0   20.0
2016-06-04  20.0   30.0   20.0
2016-06-05   0.0   40.0    0.0
2016-06-06  40.0   30.0   40.0
2016-06-07   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-08   0.0    0.0    0.0
2016-06-09   0.0    0.0    0.0

In [83]: first_valid_idx
Out[83]:
               0
data  2016-06-04
data1 2016-06-03
data2 2016-06-02
```

**OLD answer:**

```
In [38]: df.loc[df.index > df.data.last_valid_index(), 'data'] = 0

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
            data
2016-06-01   NaN
2016-06-02   NaN
2016-06-03   NaN
2016-06-04  20.0
2016-06-05  30.0
2016-06-06  40.0
2016-06-07   0.0
2016-06-08   0.0
2016-06-09   0.0
```

Comment: In my real data, I have more than one column (it's actually hundreds). Can you think of a way this fills many columns?

Comment: @MaxU This solution will not work if you have multiple gaps with NaN values in the same column, as only the last group of NaN values will be filled with 0.

Comment: @joris, it's a good point, thank you! I've noticed it and already found another way - I'm working on multiple column solution now, give me a few minutes...

Comment: @MaxU This would probably your solution for multi columns:
    def zerofill(s):
        s.ix[s.index > s.last_valid_index()] = 0
        return s

    df_full.apply(zerofill)

Comment: @TomTom101, yes, something similar to that. But i think the solutition from jezrael and DSM is much better- `df.mask(df.notnull().cummax(), df.fillna(0))`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x[:x.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index())].append(x[x.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index())+1:].fillna(0)))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.